# Only allow integers in a winform combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am currently working on programming a photo editor with c# and I am currently designing the ability to allow the pen tool to change sizes. It works flawlessly except for one problem. Here is some background information: So inside a combobox that I have, there are 10 Items, each are numbers 1 - 10. If I select one, or directly type some number into the combobox, it will set the pen size to that. The problem is, if I type a letter it gives me a

> IndexOutOfRangeException

.

Is there a way I can make it so the combobox only accepts integers and floats? Basically what I mean is if I push <kbd>3</kbd>, the pen size will change to 3. But if I push <kbd>H</kbd>, it does nothing.

Comment: check the int.TryParse https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx for integers and Single.TryParse https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t(v=vs.110).aspx for floats (if you need it)

Comment: Change the DropDownStyle to DropDownList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either of the two options. The first option is restrict the user to type in the comboobx by  Disable typing. This can be achieved by giving this code in the page_load

```
 comboBox1.DropDownStyle to ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

or Access the value like the following:

```
       if (int.TryParse(comboBox1.Text, out BreshSize))
        {
            // Proceed
        }
        else 
        { 
        //Show errror message
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, you could use the KeyPress handler to make sure just digits were typed.

```
private void txtPenToolSize_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation should allow you see if the new value is an integer and act accordingly.  You would place this inside the code when you start to check the value. "2" would be replaced with the string you are checking.

```
    int currInt = 0;
    int tryInt = 0;
    if(int.TryParse("2", out tryInt))
    {
        currInt = tryInt;         
    }
    else
    {
        //reset or display a warning
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One generic implementation for international users with different System decimal separator (locale), and texbox/combobox allowing not only `Int` numbers formats (double, float, decimal, etc..)

```
    private void comboTick_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //this allows only numbers and decimal separators
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
            && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
            && (e.KeyChar != '.') 
            && (e.KeyChar != ',') )
        {
            e.Handled = true; //ignore the KeyPress
        }
        
        //this converts either 'dot' or 'comma' into the system decimal separator
        if (e.KeyChar.Equals('.') || e.KeyChar.Equals(','))
        {
            e.KeyChar = ((System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                .NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
                .ToCharArray()[0];
            e.Handled = false; //accept the KeyPress
        }

    }
```